# Как исправить уже имеющуюся кириллицу в MySQL таблице, которая сохранилась неправильно?

Tags: mysql

Как переключить таблицу с "дефолта" на UTF-8 - я знаю.

Но вот этого не было сделано при создании, в ней куча данных, с кириллицей косяк.

Что делать?

Comment: дампнуть и загрузить заново не пойдёт?

Comment: @Fat-Zer нежелателньо

Comment: читаете данные из таблицы; приводите к нужной кодировке (iconv-ом например); апдейтите таблицу.

Comment: а при `ALTER`'е таблицы с нужной кодировкой mysql разве не догадается перекодировать всё?

Comment: @Fat-Zer `alter` - это DDL команда (а не DML) поэтому навряд ли, если конечно что-то в последних версиях mysql не поменялось.

Comment: @defrag Готового примера нет? Я новичок просто :(

Comment: @defrag понятно, что она влияет только на то как хранятся данные, а не на то что хранится, но если они загружены правильно этого должно быть вполне достаточно...

Comment: @ВодянойЗмей, добавь немного конкретики, покажи какая кодировка у таблицы сейчас (`SHOW CREATE TABLE <таблица>;`)... покажи пример неправильных данных... как загружал данные (с каким CHARSET'ом было соединение)? В какой кодировке данные реально находились при загрузке? и повоторюсь, если база меньше нескольких гигабайт и её можно остановить, то дамп будет самым простым и быстрым решением...